# How to combine notifications Flutter FirebaseMessaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I was wondering if there is a way in which I could use Firestore messaging and flutter to merge notifications such similar to how instagram does it. Where initially it will say a single person liked a post e.t.c then if more like the post it will merge it by saying bob, garry and 42 others liked a post. I have an image below which I hope makes the objective more clear[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are so-called [collapsible messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages). From the Firebase documentation:

> A collapsible message is a message that may be replaced by a new message if it has yet to be delivered to the device.
>
> A common use cases of collapsible messages are messages used to tell a mobile app to sync data from the server. An example would be a sports app that updates users with the latest score. Only the most recent message is relevant.

So in the example of Instagram messages, when somebody likes the same post, the server sends a new message that replaces the previous message, by specifying the same `collapse_key`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help so far, one more question I've tried this out however the notification only replaces the last if I turn the network connection off for the receiving device. I'd like it to replace the last message even if the the user is connected to the internet.

Comment: Just to say I've only tried this so far on IOS, so the issue may be platform based.